# Regex for number higher than 0 up to 10. integer or with precision of 2

Tags: jquery, regex

I' have been looking for a regex that will allow the following.

**Valid**

```
0.25
0.50
1
1.50
5
8
10
10.00
```

**Invalid**

```
negative numbers
0
0.00
2.555
greater than 10 
10.01
```

I'm having a hard time getting with regex. Here is that I've been working with:

```
^-{0}(([0-8].[0-9]+)|[1-10])$
```

...but it just stinks.

Here is the Jquery validation plugin I'm using.

```
    //regex for 8 hours but not working 100%
jQuery.validator.addMethod("requiredhoursrange", function (value, element) {
    if (/^-{0}(([0-7].[0-9]+)|[1-8])$/.test(value) && $("#Entry_ReasonTypeID").val() == 2) {

        return true;
    }
    return false;
});

$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("requiredhoursrange", function (options) {

    options.rules["requiredhoursrange"] = true; // mvc html helpers
    options.messages["requiredhoursrange"] = options.message;
});
```

Comment: Is it a requirement that this has to be implemented with a regex?

Comment: uhmm well.. It would easier as I already have the code to validate. I'm using javascript validation plugin.

Comment: Which javascript validation plugin? And what code do you already have? By posting it we might find some other simpler approach without using regex.

Comment: Added. My current regex checks for 8 but is not working 100% and also I need to update to 10 which I'm having problems with.

Comment: `-{0}` - as in, "-" should occur zero times? Just leave it out of the regex altogether. Do you want no decimal places or two decimals , but *not* one decimal place? I.e., is "1.5" invalid?

Comment: Have you tried the regex I have proposed hereunder?

Comment: @Allan yes. I was testing and it looks great! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go for the following regex:

```
^(10|10\.00|0\.0[1-9]|0.[1-9][0-9]|[1-9](\.[0-9][0-9])?)$
```

that will accept `10` or `10.00` or `[0.01, 0.09]` or `[0.10, 0.99]` or `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9` eventually followed by `.[00, 99]`.

I have tested it your patterns and it works.

**Valid**

```
0.25
0.50
1
1.50
5
8
10
10.00
```

**Invalid**

```
negative numbers
0
0.00
2.555
greater than 10 
10.01
```